# Undistort and center image using cv::undistort

Tags: c++, image, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have an image with distortion and its principal point not in the center. I want to use the opencv function `cv::undistort` to get rid of the distortion. Furthermore I want to move the principal point of the image to the center of the center [size_x/2, size_y/2] of the image.

What I currently do is:

```
//Creating the camera matrix with the parameters of the calibration algorithm (they are correct)
 cv::Mat cv_camera_matrix = cv::Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_64F);
cv_camera_matrix.at<double>(0,0) = projection_parameters[0]; //* incoming_image_ptr_mono8->image.cols;
cv_camera_matrix.at<double>(1,1) = projection_parameters[1]; //* incoming_image_ptr_mono8->image.rows;
cv_camera_matrix.at<double>(0,2) = projection_parameters[2]; //* incoming_image_ptr_mono8->image.cols;
cv_camera_matrix.at<double>(1,2) = projection_parameters[3]; //* incoming_image_ptr_mono8->image.rows;
cv_camera_matrix.at<double>(2,2) = 1;

//filling up of an array with the generated distortion parameters of the calibration algorithm (they are correct)

 cv::Mat distortion_coefficients = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 4, CV_64F);
distortion_coefficients.at<double>(0,0) = undistortion_parameters[0];
distortion_coefficients.at<double>(0,1) = undistortion_parameters[1];
distortion_coefficients.at<double>(0,2) = undistortion_parameters[2];
distortion_coefficients.at<double>(0,3) = undistortion_parameters[3];

cv::undistort(input_image, output_image,cv_camera_matrix, cv::getDefaultNewCameraMatrix(cv_camera_matrix,input_image.size(),true),distortion_coefficients);
```

The undistort eliminates already the distortions but I am not sure if the principal point of the image moves to the center. I choose the function  `cv::getDefaultNewCameraMatrix` in order to shift the principal point. The question is now if the center is where it should be.

Undistort uses the function: `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap()` And its mathematical description in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga7dfb72c9cf9780a347fbe3d1c47e5d5a) does not yield the results when I insert my values.

The question is now: Can I use `GetDefaultNewCameraMatrix` in order to shift the principal point? Is there another way? Which function should I use?

Also, how could I check if my principal point moved to the center?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> how could I check if my principal point moved to the center?

You could create your own image with a known pattern at a known location (for example a grid with the central intersection *on* the principle point). Then you send this simulated image through your `undistort` function, as see if the known pattern shifted to the correct location.

If you want to go want to go one step further you could project up your own simulated image with the distortion you expect with `projectPoints`, and then `undistort` it. You then have control over the entire process, and you can see exactly how the the distortion coefficients and principle point affects your images.

> Can I use GetDefaultNewCameraMatrix in order to shift the principal point? Is there another way? Which function should I use?

I think `GetDefaultNewCameraMatrix` is the wrong function to use here. It will *overwrite* the principle point to the center of the image (e.g. [200,200] for image of size [400,400]).

If the matrix `projection_parameters` already contains the principle point (e.g. from the `calibrateCamera` function), then send it as-is to `undistort`.

Like this:

```
cv::undistort(input_image, output_image,cv_camera_matrix, cv_camera_matrix, distortion_coefficients);
```

The `undistort` function should handle the principle point correctly and translate the image accordingly. That's what the function was built to do.